# Get Application name from task manager

Tags: windows, vb6, taskmanager

I am trying to get the "Task Names" of the running applications in "Applications" tab in task manager. So far I manages to get the "Image Names" from "Processes" tab in task manager. Example if I have multiple sessions of visual basic running in the "Processes" tab I will get multiple "VB6.EXE", Actually I want the process name hence the project name being running which can be found in the "Applications" Tab which usually is "ProjectName - Microsoft Visual Basic". Do you have any idea how I can do this please? below is my code:

```
Set Service = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Dim rc As Long

' Looping through all processes listed in Task manager and checking if process name is the same
For Each Process In Service.InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
    If Process.Name = "VB6.EXE" Then
    ' If InStr(Process.Name, "MyProjectName - Microsoft Visual Basic") > 0 Then
        Stop
    End If
    If Process.Name = "MyProjectName.exe" Then
        rc = MsgBox("Betswork already running! This instance will be killed!", vbCritical, App.Title)
        End
    End If
Next
```

Comment: this text is get from call [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) - so call [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) + [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) for every window. can also call [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) for associate window with process